# Accessing indices in nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists, sublist, nested-for-loop

`all_folders` is nested list of interest as below:

`all_folders = [['\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\8910\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\1112\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\1314\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\1516\\Costing\\Folder1\\'], ['\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\8910\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\1112\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\1314\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\1516\\Costing\\Folder2\\'], ['\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder3\\', '\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder3\\', '\\\\8910\\Costing\\Folder3\\', '\\\\1112\\Costing\\Folder3\\', '\\\\1314\\Costing\\Folder3\\', '\\\\1516\\Costing\\Folder3\\']]`

Trying to access 0th, 1st, 2nd... indices from nested list above.

What I am looking for is accessing addresses like this: `'\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder1\\' '\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\1234\\Costing\\Folder3\\'`
Then move to the next index in sublists:
`'\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder1\\', '\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder2\\', '\\\\4567\\Costing\\Folder3\\'`

```py
for folders in all_folders:
    for folder in folders:
    print(folder)
```

This doesn't give me what I'm trying to access. I want the output as below:

`\\1234\Costing\Folder1\ \\1234\Costing\Folder2\ \\1234\Costing\Folder3\ \\4567\Costing\Folder1\ \\4567\Costing\Folder2\ \\4567\Costing\Folder3\ \\8910\Costing\Folder1\ \\8910\Costing\Folder2\ \\8910\Costing\Folder3\ \\1112\Costing\Folder1\ \\1112\Costing\Folder2\ \\1112\Costing\Folder3\ \\1314\Costing\Folder1\ \\1314\Costing\Folder2\ \\1314\Costing\Folder3\ \\1516\Costing\Folder1\ \\1516\Costing\Folder2\ \\1516\Costing\Folder3\`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: No it doesn't. Please see above expected output.

Comment: With the added details of what you're actually expecting, then agreed, that's a different issue. Voted to re-open. Hint: Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score -1):

Well, for starters, your input is invalid, as you didn't escape the backslashes that mark the end of strings.

`'\\1516\Costing\Folder3\'` is invalid. You need to use `'\\1516\Costing\Folder3\\'` instead.

Fixing that, you get this:

```py
all_folders = [['\\1234\Costing\Folder1\\', '\\4567\Costing\Folder1\\', '\\8910\Costing\Folder1\\', '\\1112\Costing\Folder1\\', '\\1314\Costing\Folder1\\', '\\1516\Costing\Folder1\\'], ['\\1234\Costing\Folder2\\', '\\4567\Costing\Folder2\\', '\\8910\Costing\Folder2\\', '\\1112\Costing\Folder2\\', '\\1314\Costing\Folder2\\', '\\1516\Costing\Folder2\\'], ['\\1234\Costing\Folder3\\', '\\4567\Costing\Folder3\\', '\\8910\Costing\Folder3\\', '\\1112\Costing\Folder3\\', '\\1314\Costing\Folder3\\', '\\1516\Costing\Folder3\\']]
```

Secondly, you used `All_folders`. Python variables are case sensitive, so make sure you use `all_folders` instead.

Once you fix that too, using a nested `for` loop does work:

```py
for folders in all_folders:
     for folder in folders:
             print(folder)
```

```
\1234\Costing\Folder1\
\4567\Costing\Folder1\
\8910\Costing\Folder1\
\1112\Costing\Folder1\
\1314\Costing\Folder1\
\1516\Costing\Folder1\
\1234\Costing\Folder2\
\4567\Costing\Folder2\
\8910\Costing\Folder2\
\1112\Costing\Folder2\
\1314\Costing\Folder2\
\1516\Costing\Folder2\
\1234\Costing\Folder3\
\4567\Costing\Folder3\
\8910\Costing\Folder3\
\1112\Costing\Folder3\
\1314\Costing\Folder3\
\1516\Costing\Folder3\
```